# Writing Images to a PDF through a for loop, images are getting out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Script Im showing is a little simpler then what Im doing, but its still does the same problem as the original

What Im trying to do is take screenshots of a webpage, go to the next page and take a screenshot then compile it into a PDF, and i was trying to keep from having to write the image to my hard drive then write it to the PDF, then delete the image off my hard drive.

Now the images are sometimes out of order, and Im assuming its to do with not being able to write the image to the PDF fast enough, or order of operations is being screwed up. Im fairly new so im not sure. Ive tried changing the wait time, I tried saving all the images to a dictionary and doing a loop through the dictionary and it made it worse was repeating the same 4 images. I just know im not doing it right. Any suggestions.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
from fpdf import FPDF
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import io
import time
from fpdf import FPDF
import keyboard

pdf_width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
pdf_height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
t = 10
pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = [pdf_width,pdf_height])
for x in range(0, t):
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    print(x)
    mem_file = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(mem_file, 'JPEG')
    data = mem_file.getvalue()
    my_img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(my_img,0,0)
    keyboard.press_and_release('right') 
    time.sleep(2)
    if x == (t-1):
        pdf.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

[example pic](https://ibb.co/XscFNFH)

pics marked 1-3 are in order pic 4 is same as pic 2 though and not correct

Answer (score 0):

Figures after hours of trying things and reading i made a post, walked away for a few a bi tand figured it out with in 15 mins when i came back. I tried to use a dict and failed this morning so i didnt think a list would work.

```
    t = int(page_count)
    time.sleep(1)
    pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = [pdf_width,pdf_height])
    for x in range(0, t):
        string.append(ImageGrab.grab())
        print(x)
        mem_file = io.BytesIO()
        string[x].save(mem_file, 'JPEG')
        data = mem_file.getvalue()
        string[x] = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image((string[x]),0,0)
        keyboard.press_and_release('right')
        ispage_Loading(driver)  
        time.sleep(WAIT)
        if x == (t-1):
            pdf.output(dir_path+'\\'+book_name+'.pdf', 'F')
            winsound.PlaySound("*", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
            explore(dir_path)
```